# Facebook Realtime Updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I am unable to add "notifications" to the "Realtime Update Subscriptions" of my app in Facebook. In the "Realtime Updates API" page of the Apps Settings in developers.facebook.com, I have the following settings:

```
Object: user
Fields: notifications
Callback: http://myserver/callback
Verify token: my_token
```

if the Fields is set to "feed", it works, but if I attempt to save with Fields set to "notifications", it failed with the following error:

Error
Couldn't save 'user': Application cannot subscribe to notifications

Is there anything I need to configure? I have tried adding all "Permissions" under "Permissions" page.

Any input will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ – _“Note that you can not subscribe to changes on all properties and connections of the User object. Connections to which you can subscribe include: […]”_ – does it mention Notifications there …? Aha.

Comment: Now "notifications" is present in this list for user, but the message still appears. Any idea??

Comment: Same thing for `threads`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Note that you can not subscribe to changes on all properties and connections of the User object. Connections to which you can subscribe include: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, events."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

@CBroe is indeed correct... my bad :|